# Parameter can't be resolved

Tags: powershell, parameters

I must have misunderstood some tips with ParameterSetName...
I have already used it for simple combinaisons. But, this time, it doesn't work as I wish.
I try to sum up...
My script has 8 parameters. It allows me to copy files or directories from one path to another (but with elaborate rules).

To find all the ParameterSetName combinations, I filled an Excel sheet with all the combinations (even the stupidest ones!). Then I deleted the bad ones. In the end, I get 12 combinations.
Here are my parameters and their uses:

Source and Destination (string): 2 paths, mandatory everytimes.

ExcludeFiles and IncludeFiles (string array): Not required. But if I use one, I can't use the other.

ExcludeDirs and IncludeDirs (array of strings): Not required, but if I use one I can't use the other.

DirectoryOnly (switch): Not required. But if I use it, it must be alone or with ExcludeDirs or IncludeDirs only.

IgnoreLockedFiles (switch): Not required. Can be used alone and especially not with DirectoryOnly.
Here are the param declaration :

```
param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C01')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C02')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C03')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C04')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C05')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C06')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C07')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C08')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C09')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C10')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C11')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C12')][string]$Source,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C01')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C02')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C03')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C04')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C05')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C06')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C07')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C08')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C09')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C10')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C11')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C12')][string]$Destination,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C10')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C11')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C12')][string[]]$ExcludeFiles,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C07')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C08')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C09')][string[]]$IncludeFiles,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C05')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C06')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C09')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C12')][string[]]$ExcludeDirs,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C03')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C04')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C08')][Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ParameterSetName='C11')][string[]]$IncludeDirs,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C02')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C04')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C06')][switch]$DirectoryOnly=$false,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C01')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C03')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C05')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C07')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C08')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C09')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C10')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C11')][Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C12')][switch]$IgnoreLockedFiles
)
```

However, when I call my script with :

```
myscript.ps1 -Source C:\theSource -Destination C:\theDestination -ExcludeDirs A
```

I get an error :

```
Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters
```

I understand the error, but I can't fix it. I wonder if the problem does not comme from default values or switch parameters..

Help welcome !

Comment: There are 4 distinct parameter sets (C05, C06, C09 and C12) that could all satisfy the combination of parameters you've explicitly supplied - hence the ambiguity, in absence of a default parameter set. I'd suggest starting by removing any parameter sets tied to `DirectoryOnly` or `IgnoreLockedFiles` - simply check inside the function whether someone passed both

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, hi. I simplified the parameters to understand your answer.
param (
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='C01')]
[string]$Source,
[string]$Destination,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C01')][switch]$DirectoryOnly=$false,
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ParameterSetName='C02')][switch]$IgnoreLockedFiles=$false
)
I call my script just with source and destination, but I still have the same error. I'm lost :(

Comment: You don't need to associate parameter set names with `$Source` and `$Destination` _at all_ - since they're always mandatory anyways :)

Comment: It's not associated ;) "C01" is just before DirectoryOnly ; "C02" is just before IgnoreLockedFiles.